# unicode to Percent encoding for URIs

Tags: java, blackberry, unicode, java-me, urlencode

I ma trying to convert a unicode to Percent encoding for URIs, am using java-me for blackberry application. am using this url http://www.rishida.net/tools/conversion/ to convert my words.
can someone please send me blackberry java code for this or even converting arabic to Percent encoding for URIs.

Answer (score 2):

[`java.net.URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) does this. If you're on Micro Edition and don't have direct access to the Standard API, you could try reusing the code from that class.